# Class has no member name 'setAttribute'

Tags: qt, touch, zooming, pinch, qquickitem

I have a class which displays a map and therefore has to inherit from `QQuickItem`. I wish to integrate the pinch zoom function into the map display class however it was not possible to `setAttribute(Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents)`.

```
MapWidget::MapWidget(QQuickItem* parent) : QQuickPaintedItem(parent)
{
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents);
}
```

I then added QWidget as a class to be inherited from but of course there was a conflict with QObject.

Does anybody know how else I can integrate a pinch zoom function into my class? `QQuickItem` is however not possible to be removed or the restructuring for the map display will be immense.

Comment: Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents is a property for widgets, not for Quick Items

Comment: Yes, I found that out too after the first error message. How can I then implement a multi-touch zoom function for the map display class?

Comment: Look at the Qt Quick Demo - Photosurface as starting point.